# Binary operator expected in my bash script

Tags: bash, shell, helper

With this bash script, I check the directory for *xls files, and if they are, I send them for conversion using ssconvert to *xlsx.
All this works if there is only one file in the directory. If there are several or more in the directory, a "binary operator expected" error appears. Please help me fix my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
test -f /home/doc/testy/*.xls && for f in /home/doc/testy/*.xls; do ssconvert "$f" "${f%.xls}.xlsx";
chown www-data:www-data "${f%.xls}.xlsx";
rm -f -- "$f"; done
sleep 10
done
```

Comment: You might want torun your script with `bash -x` and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test -f` can only handle 1 file at a time, but you can use `find` instead. I don't know how to combine find's `-exec` with your `${f%.xls}.xlsx`, so i made this look a little bit different.

```
#!/bin/bash -u                                                                                                                                                                                

DIRECTORY=/home/doc/testy/
export EXTENSION_OLD=xls
export EXTENSION_NEW=xlsx

function doConvert {
    fOld="$1"
    fNew="${fOld%.$EXTENSION_OLD}.$EXTENSION_NEW"
    ssconvert "$fOld" "$fNew";
    chown www-data:www-data "$fNew";
    rm -f -- "$fOld";
}
export -f doConvert

cd $DIRECTORY
while true; do
    find -type f -name "*.$EXTENSION_OLD" -exec bash -c "doConvert {}" \;
    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a very beautiful and correct code!

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume you are intentionally creating an infinite loop to watch the
specified directory for newly generated files.
You need to check the existence of the file *within* the `for f in ..`
loop.
Then would you please try:

```
while true; do
    for f in /home/doc/testy/*.xls; do
        if [[ -f $f ]]; then
            newfile=${f}x
            ssconvert "$f" "$newfile"
            chown www-data:www-data "$newfile"
            rm -f -- "$f"
        fi
    done
    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a very simple, beautiful and correct execution of the code) :)